# How to use Mollie Api with firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, mollie

I could need some help setting up the node.js api from mollie with firebase cloud functions. I tried to use parts of the cloudfunction setting up paypal guide but didn't get it to work yet. I'm new to cloud functions and node.js so i have a hard time getting it done. I am using hard coded payment properties for testing purposes. I am using a blaze subscribtion to be able to do requests to non-Google services The code i have so far:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
Mollie = require("mollie-api-node");
mollie = new Mollie.API.Client;
mollie.setApiKey("test_GhQyK7Gkkkkkk**********");
querystring = require("querystring");
fs = require("fs");

exports.pay = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    console.log('1. response', res)
mollie.payments.create({
    amount:      10.00,
    method: Mollie.API.Object.Method.IDEAL,
    description: "My first iDEAL payment",
    redirectUrl: "https://dummyse-afgerond",
    webhookUrl:  "https://us-c90e9d.cloudfunctions.net/process",
    testmode: true
}, (payment)=> {
    if (payment.error) {
        console.error('errrr' , payment.error);
        return response.end();
      }
    console.log('3. payment.getPaymentUrl()', payment.getPaymentUrl());
    res.redirect(302, payment.getPaymentUrl());
});

});

exports.process = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

let _this = this;
this.body = "";
req.on("data", (data)=> {
    console.log('_this.body += data', _this.body += data)
  return _this.body += data;
});
req.on("end", ()=> {
    console.log('hier dan?')
  let mollie, _ref;
  _this.body = querystring.parse(_this.body);
  if (!((_ref = _this.body) !== null ? _ref.id : void 0)) {
    console.log('res.end()', res.end())
    return res.end();
  }
})

    mollie.payments.get(
        _this.body.id
    , (payment) => {

        if (payment.error) {
            console.error('3a. err', payment.error);
            return response.end();
          }

        console.log('4a. payment', payment);
        console.log('5a. payment.isPaid()', payment.isPaid());


        if (payment.isPaid()) {
          /*
            At this point you'd probably want to start the process of delivering the
            product to the customer.
          */
            console.log('6a. payment is payed!!!!!!!!!!')
        } else if (!payment.isOpen()) {
          /*
            The payment isn't paid and isn't open anymore. We can assume it was
            aborted.
          */
         console.log('6a. payment is aborted!!!!!!!!!!')
        }
        res.end();
    });
});
```

this is mollies api guide: 
https://github.com/mollie/mollie-api-node

this is paypal cloud function guide: 
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/paypal

UPDATE:
I updated the code. The error i get now is that all properties of the payment variable are undefined in the procces function (webhook). and the payment.isPaid() function says false while it should say true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the same when I first tried to get mollie working in firebase cloud functions, this:

```
let _this = this;
this.body = "";
req.on("data", (data)=> {
    console.log('_this.body += data', _this.body += data)
  return _this.body += data;
});
req.on("end", ()=> {
    console.log('hier dan?')
  let mollie, _ref;
  _this.body = querystring.parse(_this.body);
  if (!((_ref = _this.body) !== null ? _ref.id : void 0)) {
    console.log('res.end()', res.end())
    return res.end();
  }
})
```

is not necessary.

my webhook endpoint is much simpler, directly using the request & response that functions provides:

```
exports.paymentsWebhook = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
// ...
console.log("request.body: ", request.body);
console.log("request.query: ", request.query);
mollie.payments.get(request.body.id, function (payment) {
    console.log("payment", payment);
    if (payment.error) {
        console.error('payment error: ', payment.error);
        response.end();
    }
    //checking/processing the payment goes here...
    response.end();
});
});
```

Comment: your the best :)